# Gap in time series not appearing

Tags: d3.js

I am working with time series data that omit data for the weekend. When graphing these time series in D3 v4 the graph interpolates over the weekend. See the following URL for an illustration (including code, data, and graph output):

[No records for weekend](https://bl.ocks.org/quantbo/cde60e268f21ff0017a5e380cbde37bd)

Instead, I want a gap at the weekend; graph stopping on Friday and resuming on Monday.

I could fix the problem by creating dummy records for the weekend, with values 'NA', and using the D3 `defined` method, as shown in the following:

[Data has NA records](http://bl.ocks.org/cgroll/c5e7bdb5dffb12818623)

However, generating dummy records feels to me like excessively heavy lifting. Is there a simple, natural way to get D3 to leave a gap when time series records are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a simple, natural way to get D3 to leave a gap when time series records are missing?

Unfortunately no, that's the normal behaviour of a time scale. According to Mike Bostock, D3 creator,

> A d3 time scale should be used when you want to display time as a continuous, quantitative variable, such as when you want to take into account the fact that days can range from 23-25 hours due to daylight savings changes, and years can vary from 365-366 days due to leap years.

So, the time scale was created having in mind a continuous time.

Your current approach in the line generator...

```
.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); })
```

... doesn't work because all the dates in your CSV have values, and d3 will connect the dots.

That having been said, if you want to **keep** the gap, just use dummy records (as `null` or any non numeric value) for the weekends and `line.defined`, as in your second link.

Comment: It appears to me that your method would not generate a gap at the weekend. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, it generates the chart without the weekend gaps. If you want a gap, just use `null` and `line.defined`, as in your second image. As you want to keep the gap, I edited the answer.